# import CSV file into postgres via php in web page

Tags: php, postgresql, csv

Hi I'm trying to build a web interface that will allow people to import the contents of a csv file into a postgresql database. Below is the php component of what I'm trying to do, however when I run I just get "There was a problem uploading your data:" from my die command but with no other error.

For this example, I have hardcoded a value for the csv file, however the intent is for the user to point at a csv file on their machine or network location.

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {
// attempt a connection
$dbh = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=blah user=user password=pass123");
if (!$dbh) {
die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
}
// execute query
$sql = "COPY personaldetails(name, email, postaladdress, phone, username, password) FROM '../Test/Book1.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV";

$result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
if (!$result) {
die("There was a problem uploading you data: " . pg_last_error());
}

echo "Data successfully inserted!";

// free memory
pg_free_result($result);

// close connection
pg_close($dbh);
}   

?>
```

I appreciate any help that can be offered.

Comment: There's nothing from pg_last_error()?

Comment: You might be able to adapt my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66482947/5075276 My solution works best with PDO but there is a way to adapt it using pg_connect, which I also give. The key is using either pg_copy_from (with pg_connect) or pgsqlCopyFromArray (with PDO); both are well-documented and don't require the sort of privileges that COPY FROM file requires, nor do they require PHP actually subject the file to more than a few commands of minimal processing.

Answer (score 4):

`COPY FROM file` must be run by a superuser account and this restriction makes it generally unsuitable for web usage

Excerpt from the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

> COPY naming a file is only allowed to database superusers, since it
>   allows reading or writing any file that the server has privileges to
>   access.

But PHP provides support for `COPY FROM stdin` which does not have this restriction.
This example from php documentation shows how it's done:

```
  $conn = pg_pconnect("dbname=foo");
  pg_query($conn, "create table bar (a int4, b char(16), d float8)");
  pg_query($conn, "copy bar from stdin");
  pg_put_line($conn, "3\thello world\t4.5\n");
  pg_put_line($conn, "4\tgoodbye world\t7.11\n");
  pg_put_line($conn, "\\.\n");
  pg_end_copy($conn);
```

In the case of a file, you'll need to open the file with php functions and feed it line  by line to the postgres connection with `pg_put_line()`